# Can't access google cloud client on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, google-cloud-storage

I'm tring to make a AWS Lambda function receives a file from google cloud storage to process and insert to AWS RDS DB.

I set my lambda handler like this:

```
import json
from google.cloud import storage

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket_name = 'my-bucket-name'
    blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name)
    for blob in blobs:
        print(blob.name)
    return {
        'statuscode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Also I set my env var like this:
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: serviceAccountKey.json

This key is from google cloud storage service account(make private account key)

If i run this code on local vscode, it works.

However on aws lambda, it doesn't works.

```
Test Event Name
saveRequestEvent

Response
{
    "errormessage": "2022-03-08T22:46:40.714Z fed88616-fbf6-48ca-998f-8accbab756aa Task timed out after 30.03 seconds"
}
```

Is there any problem on my code? Or need to set firewall options?

Thanks.

Comment: You should include error messages inline, not in an external image. Your request timed out at 30 seconds so it's likely that either your Lambda function has no route to the GCS endpoint or that the operation that you're running literally takes more than 30 seconds. If you configured the Lambda function to connect to a VPC, then that doesn't appear to be necessary so re-configure it outside of VPC and then re-test.

Comment: Sorry I got missed on my post. I included error message on my post. Will gonna check my VPC. Thanks

Comment: Problem solved. It was because my wrong VPC Router table and NAT settings. Thank you for your answer!